Unable to access gRPC service though Yarp Gateway in .Net Core
I have created a gRPC service in Asp.net core Web API using nuget packages - Grpc.AspNetCore 2.57.0, Grpc.Tools 2.64.0, Google.Protobuf 3.27.2.
I am able to access it successfully through my .Net Core Web application. However, when I try to access it through the Yarp Gateway, getting 404 error. Can someone please help me to get rid of this issue?
Exception Details : Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented", Detail="Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 404")
gRPC service Proto file
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcService.CatalogAPI";

package CatalogGrpcService;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service CatalogGrpcAPI{
    rpc GetAllCatalogs (google.protobuf.Empty) returns (CatalogListResponse);    
}

// A Catalog resource.
message CatalogModel {
  string catalogId = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string description = 3;
  float price = 4;
}

// Response message to GetAllCatalogs method.
message CatalogListResponse {
    repeated CatalogModel catalogs = 1;
}

Aspnet Core Web Application client
//var grpcChannel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:7005"); // Works well with this direct URL of the gRPC service
var grpcChannel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:7700"); // Gives error with this https URL of Yarp Api Gateway
//var grpcChannel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:5000"); // Gives error with this http URL of Yarp Api Gateway

var client = new CatalogGrpcAPI.CatalogGrpcAPIClient(grpcChannel);
var response = await client.GetAllCatalogsAsync(requestModel);

Yarp Gateway config
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "http": {
      "Url": "http://localhost:5000",
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    },
    "https": {
      "Url": "https://localhost:7700"
    }
  }
},
"Yarp": {
  "Routes": {
    "catalog-route": {
      "ClusterId": "catalogCluster",
      "Match": {
        "Path": "/CatalogGrpcService.CatalogGrpcAPI/{**catch-all}"
      },
      "Transforms": [ { "PathPattern": "{**catch-all}" } ]
    }
  },
  "Clusters": {
    "catalogCluster": {
      "HttpRequest": {
        "Version": "2",
        "VersionPolicy": "RequestVersionExact"
      },
      "Destinations": {
        "catalogCluster/destination1": {
          "Address": "https://localhost:7005/"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Hi Sandeep, I'm not too famaliar with yarp, but from the following line it looks like you're removing the service name from the path before forwarding the request.
"Transforms": [ { "PathPattern": "{**catch-all}" } ]

The path should contain the fully qualified service name followed by the method name. The missing service name could be the reason why the server returns 404.
Can you try adding the the full name and see if the server responds correctly?
